# Why do I get odd AutoMapped results if I map directly from IEnumerable to IEnumerable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, automapper-2

I am having a strange issue with AutoMapper.

If I do the following

```
//Get my entities from EF repository
var movements = _movementRepository.AllIncluding(movement => movement.Asset, movement => movement.Job,movement => movement.Asset.MinorEquipmentType);
var model = new List<AssetMovementDetail>();
foreach (var assetMovementDetail in movements)
{
     model.Add(Mapper.Map<AssetMovementDetail>(assetMovementDetail));
}
```

This works perfectly and gives me the results if I expect.

If alternatively I change model to be generated like:

```
var model = Mapper.Map<List<AssetMovementDetail>>(movements);
```

The results are different and have the same total number of results but many of the results are duplicates of each other and others are missing. Am I doing something wrong? Is this not how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map list to list, rather than automatically getting mapping from just one list...
Hence unpexpected berhaviour.
To see what I mean, please take a look into this posting: [Mapping Lists using Automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589471/mapping-lists-using-automapper)

**Edit**

Maybe you have the same issue that was answered over there? [Extra iterations in a foreach in an AutoMapper map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460177/extra-iterations-in-a-foreach-in-an-automapper-map). Please take a look, maybe it solves, or gives you some ideas?

It also maybe related to *lazy (deferred) loading* in your initial linq statement.

**Edit 2**

Here is the code from my own project that does successfully what you trying to do:

```
var dbResources = _db.GetResourcesForBusiness();
var vmResources = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DBResource>, IEnumerable<VMResource>>(dbResources);
```

its a bit different format for one shot deal compared to what you're using, try to use this, see if it works for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still produces the same weirdness even if  I use Mapper.Map<List<AssetMovement>, List<AssetMovementDetail>>(movements);

Comment: I am using all the includes required and so it shouldn't be Lazy loading anything. I do wonder if this is a bug but it seems so fundamental it must be something I am doing that is non standard but I don't know what. Will maybe post it as an issue.

Comment: Hard to tell you what is happening in your case. I can only tell you that I personally used list to list mapping with no issues. Please look at the edit #2 for that.